# Mvc приложение на js

Tags: javascript

Насколько реализуемо mvc приложение на js? Как при этом подключать разные классы из разных файлов? Может есть примеры? Пишу на чистом js и typescript

Comment: [mvc js boiler plate, первая ссылка в гугле](https://github.com/oguzhanoya/express-mvc-boilerplate)

Comment: @MoloF, данный пример использует кучу сторонних библиотек, меня интересует приложение на чистом js или минимум сторонних библиотек